# How to convert foreach into linq queries or lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

How to convert this foreach to linq???
MyReport.Elements consists of 5 elements.

```
foreach( var i in MyReport.Elements)
{
      if(i.caption == table.caption)
       { 
         newName = i.uname;
       }
}
```

I have tired to convert this into linq as below but it didn't work out.

```
newName = MyReport.Elements.ForEach(i => i.caption.Equals(table.caption)? i.uname : null );
```

Comment: Whats the point of assigning `newName` if it's just going to get overwritten?

Comment: LINQ is query and you should use it to get data, not to modify data. Using foreach in the case is fine, though you could just call Last with predicate that satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your example will continue to assign as long as there are matches.  Because of this, the only one that actually matters within the context you've given is the *last* exact match:

```
// C# 6
newName = MyReport.Elements.Where(x => x.caption == table.caption).LastOrDefault()?.uname;
```

Live/REPL example right here: https://repl.it/ETVT/2

Comment: No i dont want first or default match.. there are more than 5 elements in MyReport.Elements and i want the exact "caption" match

Comment: This is an exact match.  I'm asking if it's important to _re-assign_ on every match.  Can your report dataset contain more than one exact match?  If not, or if you don't care, then this works great.

Comment: Yes..my report dataset contains more than one match so i  need to re-assign on everymatch.

Comment: Well this now does that too.  Enjoy.